# Cypress - verify if each table row in one column contains the same item

Tags: cypress, cypress-each

I have a table, however some kind of ag-grid, created by DIV's, not real table element:

```js
<div role="row" row-index="1" >
<div col-id="name">Name 1</div>
<div col-id="age">25</div>
</div>

<div role="row" row-index="2" >
<div col-id="name">Name 1</div>
<div col-id="age">25</div>
</div>
```

I want to verify, if EACH field with `col-id="name"` contains the same item. I am testing kind of filtering, so if user filters the Name 1, I want to check each row, if there is only Name 1 and nothing else.

As each field which I need to check has the same col-id, I tried it this way:

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]').contains('Name 1')
```

or

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]').should('contain','Name 1')
```

but both cases passes even if some field contains another name, because it finds at least one match.

How to assert that each field with `col-id="name"` should contain ONLY Name 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `.each()` to test the elements individually

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]')
  .each($el => {
    expect($el.text()).to.eq('Name 1')
  })
```

---

**Without .each()**

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]')
  .should($els => {
    const names = [...$els].map(el => el.innerText)
    expect(names.every(name => name === 'Name 1').to.eq(true)
  })
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way, however I wanted to avoid iteration, but seems I can't. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can verify the combined text of all elements

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'Name 1'.repeat(2))  // assuming two elements, equals "Name 1Name1"
```

or, this is better for asynchronous fetching of name

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]')
  .should('have.text', 'Name 1'.repeat(2))  // equals "Name 1Name1"
```

---

**When element count is unknown**

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]')
  .then($els => {
    const count = $els.length
    cy.wrap($els).should('have.text', 'Name 1'.repeat(count))  
  })
```

Comment: but I don't know how many rows there will be, can't just repeat it twice

Comment: Can count the elements returned from get - will update.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to apply assertion and just print out statements stating whether the element was found/not found, you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('div[col-id="name"]').each(($ele, index) => {
  if ($ele.text().trim() == 'Name 1') {
    cy.log('Item Found at position ' + index)
  } else {
    cy.log(
      'Expected Item Not found at position ' +
        index +
        '. Instead the item was ' +
        $ele.text().trim()
    )
  }
})
```