# Cypress - verify if each table row in one column contains the same item and ignoring header

Tags: cypress, filtering

I have a filtered table, a grid table created by DIVs, so no real table elements, that I want to confirm that my filter has worked in but the ways I have tried keep trying to also check the header which is then telling me that my results are wrong

```
  cy.get('div[data-field="name"]')
    .then($col => {
      const count = $col.length
        .wrap($col)
        .should('have.text', 'Bob'.repeat(count))
    })
```

I have 3 bobs in my example, but it is also viewing the header so I am getting an error telling me that it is trying to find 3 instances of Bob but also finds Name, so finds 4.

If I try

```
  cy.get('div[data-field="name"]')
    .each($col => {
      expect($col.text()).to.eq('Bob')
    })
```

It fails as it tells me the first entry is 'Name' as it is finding the header and I am not sure how to avoid it counting/reading the header.

I'm sure its something simple that I am missing and not thinking of but any help is appreciated!

NOTE: I got both these ways of checking from this other stack answer [Cypress - verify if each table row in one column contains the same item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71936805/cypress-verify-if-each-table-row-in-one-column-contains-the-same-item)

Comment: Can you provide the HTML with this? The examples are a little hard to follow without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to solve this, here are a couple.

For the first sample, take one off the count (since there is only one header)

```js
  cy.get('div[data-field="name"]')
    .then($col => {
      const count = $col.length
        .wrap($col)
        .should('have.text', 'Bob'.repeat(count-1))
    })
```

For the second sample, don't look at the first element

```js
  cy.get('div[data-field="name"]')
    .each(($col, index) => {
      if (index > 0) {
        expect($col.text()).to.eq('Bob')
      }
    })
```